# Variation of the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

We know that the Riemann Zeta function
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$ converges when $Re(s) > 1$. How do you prove the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(z+n)^s}$$
converges when $Re(s) > 0$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$ except for some $z$. Any idea what restriction we need to have on $z$ besides $z$ cannot be negative integer?

Comment: This is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), and proofs of its absolutel convergence in $\Re s>1$ for fixed $z$ are essentially the same as for the zeta function itself (compare the tail of the series to a $p$-integral).

Comment: @Greg Martin Can I ask you another question? What if the series is alternating? How do I prove that?

Comment: @Smith: For *absolute* convergence, it doesn't matter if the series is alternating or not.

Comment: The (first-year calculus) alternating series test shows that it converges when $s$ and $z$ are real and $s>0$. And then there are ways (standard in the study of Dirichlet series) to deduce that if the series converges for some $s_0\in\Bbb C$, then it converges for every $s\in\Bbb C$ with $\Re s>\Re s_0$. You can also pair the terms manually and prove the absolute convergence of the resulting series, perhaps using the mean value theorem to estimate the paired terms.

Comment: @GregMartin Is there any reasons when Re(q)>0 for the Hurwiz zeta functions, $q$ is the notation in the link that you share. If Re(q)<0, does that affects the convergence of that series?

Comment: Good question; I believe that $\Re q>0$ isn't essential, but only that all of the individual summands are defined—that is, $q$ is not a nonpositive integer (in your notation, $z$ is not a negative integer). Indeed if $q=-3.45$ say, then the sum of the first four terms is an entire function, and whatever convergence proof we have for $\Re q>0$, it should also work on the series for $q=-3.45$ with its first four terms deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked the same question [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721375/the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frace2n-pi-ixwns-converges)

If $z$ is a negative integer then $(z+n)^{-s}$ is undefined.

Thus we assume it is not. For $\Re(s) > 1$ it converges absolutely. For $\Re(s) > 0$ we need a partial summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n (z+n)^{-s} = (\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n) (z+N)^{-s}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(\sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^m) ((z+m)^{-s}-(z+m+1)^{-s})$$
The first term $\to 0$, and for the second term we use that $$(z+m)^{-s}-(z+m+1)^{-s} = \int_0^1 s(z+x)^{-s-1}dx= O(s(z+m)^{-s-1})$$
Finally we let $N\to \infty$.